# Why isn't this extension method working (C#, string array)

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with making an extension method; firstly, here's the code:

```
public static string Replace(this string str, string[] oldValues, string newValue)
{
    string result = str;

    for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.Length; i++)
    {
        result.Replace(oldValues[i], newValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Sadly, the above method isn't working when I use it like this:

```
if (line.StartsWith("#include"))
{
    string[] valuesToReplace = { "include", "<", ">", "#" };
    line = line.Replace(valuesToReplace, "");
}
```

I'm just... so confused as to why this isn't working; can some one please help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: Place this method inside static class.

Comment: Please be clearer: what are you seeing happen, and what did you expect to happen? Does it compile? Is an exception being thrown? Does it execute but not do what you expect? "Isn't working" is far too broad. (Hint though: you're not using the result of `string.Replace`. That has nothing to do with extension methods...)

Comment: @AnupamSingh The method is inside a static class?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, I just figured the issue would have been something that I was overlooking; which someone would pick up on instantly. Which just so happened to be the case.

Comment: Yes, but in being more precise in what you were asking - and putting together a [mcve], debugging through it etc - you would probably have found that yourself, without having to ask anyone. Stack Overflow should be your last line of defence *after* research etc... so that by the time you're asking a question, it's ready in a very clear, reproducible manner.

Answer (score 7):

## You cannot modify a string, it is immutable.

You can only create a new one.
When you change a string, with replace or similar, A new copy is created and returned. Therefor you must save the returned string, to be able to further edit it.

```
public static string Replace(this string str, string[] oldValues, string newValue)
{
    string result = str;

    for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result.Replace(oldValues[i], newValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

[You can read more about System.String here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string)

Comment: Oh my, how could I have been so blind. Thank you. I can't believe I did that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working, because Replace does not modify the string you send to it. In C#, strings cannot change once they are created. Rather, String.Replace creates a brand new string after doing its job, and returns it.

Change it to:
result = result.Replace(oldValues[i], newValue);

Andre beat me to it :)